Using gradle configuration cache + the ecilpse plugins
Gradle has the configuration cache feature but according to the spec, not all gradle core plugins support it YET. The eclipse plugins is one of them (is the support for that coming any time soon?).
Are there alternatives to the plugin when using configuration cache or the only way to run a project that currently uses the plugin is to get rid of it and do custom implementation of the needed features?
